# How to get the percentage of my brute forcer?

Tags: python

I need help on understanding how to calculate the percentage, of my scripts progress as it takes a while depending on the [CPU, clock speed, RAM, and length of the target password_list].

Would you point me in the right direction, or show me a snippet of how to calculate this?

```
import itertools, math
Alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890") # Add or remove whatevs you think will be in the password you're cracking (example, [symbols])
counter = 1
CharLength = 1
start_range = int(raw_input("Enter start range: ") # <<< To begin brute force
end_range = int(raw_input("Enter end range: ")) # <<< To end brute force
filename = "bruteforce_%r-%r.txt" % (start_range, end_range)
```

This below is where the calculation would be done; unfortunately percentages just nope my brain will not let me understand em :/

```
# Math below don't let it bore you :)
y = len(Alphabet)
x = len(start_range)
total = math.pow(x, y)
f = open(filename, 'a')
# Math above don't let it bore you :(
```

The First for loop

```
for CharLength in range(start_range, end_range):
    passwords = (itertools.product(Alphabet, repeat = CharLength))
```

The Second for loop

```
    for i in passwords:
        counter += 1
        i = str(i)
        i = i.replace("[", "")
        i = i.replace("]", "")
        i = i.replace("'", "")
        i = i.replace(" ", "")
        i = i.replace(",", "")
        i = i.replace("(", "")
        i = i.replace(")", "")
        f.write(i)
        f.write('\n')
        print "%r:  %r" % (i, percentage) # <--- *Display percentages on second format argument
        pass
```

Comment: I gave you +1 just because your question sounds funny. But I'm almost sure it's a duplicate.

Comment: If it is can you send a link because i cannot seem to find it explaining how in my situation thanks buddy !

Comment: If you have a variable `i` that is iterating through a range from `start_range` to `end_range`, then a percentage just expresses the fraction of stuff done (`i/length`) out of 100. So `percent = 100 * i/(end_range - start_range)`. However, your code may have other issues, it is not clear.

Comment: It is clear i want to calculate the percentage of the progress explaining to me how i code isnt helping bruh.

Comment: Percentages are easy... right? `(items_processed / items_total) * 100`. No code, just maths... bruh.

Comment: Right that worked wonders haha love you man !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [python-progressbar](http://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/). From their git repo:

> The `ProgressBar` class manages the current progress, and the format of
>   the line is given by a number of widgets. A widget is an object that
>   may display differently depending on the state of the progress bar.
>   There are three types of widgets:
>
> - a string, which always shows itself
> - a `ProgressBarWidget`, which may return a different value every time its    update method is called
> - a `ProgressBarWidgetHFill`, which is like `ProgressBarWidget`, except it    expands to fill the remaining width of the line.

Example:

```
import progressbar as pb

progress = pb.ProgressBar(widgets=_widgets, maxval = 400000).start()
progvar = 0

for i in range(400000):  
    # Your code here
    progress.update(progvar + 1)
    progvar += 1
```

Output:

```
Progress: |####################################################            |80%
```

Comment: That code you gave me is not what i need also as i need  code that just simply gathers the percentage and displays it alongside my current password.